# How can i execute a job properly with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The routes are like this:  `get:'/hi', to: 'tables#execute'`

I have this controller but I don't know how can I execute it

```
class TableController < ApplicationController
  def execute
    CurrentJob.set(wait: 2.minutes).perform_later(self)
    render plain: 'OK'
  end
end
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError in TableController#execute

Unsupported argument type: TableController
```

**Note:** I have modified my controller like this:

```
def execute
    CurrentJob.perform_later params[:name]
    render plain: 'OK'
end
```

Let me know how to execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`perform_later`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Enqueuing/ClassMethods.html#method-i-perform_later) takes what you want to pass along to the job. These are passed to the job's `perform` method. It only takes certain types which it knows how to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

> By default the arguments must be either String, Integer, Float, NilClass, TrueClass, FalseClass, BigDecimal, Symbol, Date, Time, DateTime, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone, ActiveSupport::Duration, Hash, ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, Array, Range, or GlobalID::Identification instances, although this can be extended by adding custom serializers.

A Controller object is not allowed, and also doesn't make much sense to pass to a background job. It's the controller's job to decide what to pass to the job, probably something from [`params`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters).

See [Creating A Job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#creating-a-job) in Active Job Basics for more.

Comment: i am new with rails, please how can i solve my problem?

Comment: @logger If you have a specific problem or error, we can help. However, we can't teach you Rails here. You should start with the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/) and refer to [the documentation for specific methods](https://api.rubyonrails.org/).